# Why do node.js crypto use binary strings?

Tags: node.js, binary, cryptography, node-crypto

In the [node.js API 0.6.2](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.2/api/), it is stated under the Buffer module:

> 'binary' - A way of encoding raw binary data into strings by using
>   only the first 8 bits of each character. This encoding method is
>   deprecated and should be avoided in favor of Buffer objects where
>   possible. This encoding will be removed in future versions of Node.

In the Crypto module however, the binary strings are used in many places, e.g. in the `.digest()` methods. Why do they not comply with their own conventions by using buffers there instead?

Comment: I guess the API is older than the guideline. Deprecated stuff was once used, until somebody realized that it's a bad idea.

Comment: Well you can always fork, make changes and make a pull request. That's how the FOSS works.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize it was by design. @alFReDNSH Not necessarily, that would require specific knowledge or research, which I do not have. However I subscribed to [a related issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1393) in the issue queue.

Comment: Not to mention that this would be backwards-incompatible. Everyone who wants to convert crypto output into a Buffer has to convert the crypto-output strings using the binary encoding. It doesn't seem to me that changing the crypto output is a practical idea.